# Merge array with same value and display the other array as value

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm a newbie on PHP and I found this problem on my project. 
I have this array:

```
Array
(

 [0] => Array
    (
        [count] => 1
        [account] => 14
        [amt] => 1000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [count] => 1
        [account] => 11
        [amt] => 124
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [count] => 1
        [account] => 12
        [amt] => 2345
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [count] => 1
        [account] => 14
        [amt] => 2345
    )

)
```

and I'd like to transform it into this format

```
Array
(
[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 1000
                [count] => 1
                [volume] => 1000
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 124
                [count] => 0
                [volume] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 2345
                [count] => 1
                [volume] => 2345
            )

    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 1000
                [count] => 0
                [volume] => 0
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 124
                [count] => 1
                [volume] => 124
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 2345
                [count] => 0
                [volume] => 0
            )

    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 1000
                [count] => 0
                [volume] => 0
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 124
                [count] => 0
                [volume] => 0
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 2345
                [count] => 1
                [volume] => 2345
            )

    )

 )
```

As you may notice the `account` key become the key of the new array and the array inside the value has all the array on the 1st array. Please help. It's like a hardcore array and I really need it for my project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($origArray as $val)
{
   $val['volume'] = $val['count'] * $val['amt'];
   $account = $val['account'];
   unset($val['account']);  
   $newArray[$account][]=$val;
}
```

**Edit**

Ok I think maybe this is near where you want, though I don't understand why there are 3 results in each account when there are 4 to begin with.

```
$newArray = array();
$accounts = array();
foreach ($origArray as $val) {
    $accounts[$val['account']] = $val['account'];
}

foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    foreach ($origArray as $val) {
        $val['count'] = $account == $val['account'] ? $val['count'] : 0;
        $val['volume'] = $val['count'] * $val['amt'];
        unset($val['account']);
        $newArray[$account][] = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: The $account on $newArray[$account] is not displaying its value and is only loop once..i cant even get it why there is no value..

Comment: `$account` is being used to append the array to the index of the corresponding account in `$newArray` it is not meant to show as per your requirement. If you want it to show in the array remove `unset($val['account']);`

Comment: there will be 3 array because the last 2 array has the same amt value with different account.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$final_array = array();
$dataset = YOUR FIRST ARRAY;

foreach($dataset as $data)
{
    $account = $data['account'];
    unset($data['account'])
    $final_array[$account][] = $data;
}
```

This should do what you need. Although i have no clue where volume comes from in your second array

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Volume is the product of count and amt..
I tried your code and $account is not displaying its value. The output is different, notice the count on the 2nd array..